# Gravel patches in concrete after sanding

Tags: concrete, sealing

We recently sanded our concrete  in our garage to prepare for a reseal. These gravel patches came up randomly throughout the space. How do we fix this before resealing?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't need fixing, it's entirely cosmetic.

Your options are

1. ignore it, it's harmless.
2. re-sand the floor so the agregate shows through everywhere. some people like this textured look.
3. cover the floor with leveling compound. you'll get the old uniform grey colour.
4. use an opaque sealer. the sealer can be tinted to any colour you want.

Answer (score 0):

You either put a skim coat or levelling coat over the whole floor or live with it like it is now.